# My Phone will not recognize USB connected

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, usb, stock-rom, samsung-galaxy-avant

There is no USB options when I connect to pc. I have tried a Galaxy Avant phone with the same cable and works, so it is not the computer or the cable. I have turned off and on USB debugging. I have tried so many " solutions"  and still nothing.

Phone: Rooted Galaxy Avant (T-mobile)
Kitkat 4.4.2

Comment: sorry if i misspeled something XD

Comment: If you notice any of youre own, you are free to edit your own posts. Just click the 'edit' link under the tags.

Comment: Try changing the device connection protocol. My device only works in ptp.

Comment: @EthanZ hey m8, thanks for responding so quickly. Could you tell me how? Im kind of a big noob. :)

Comment: It should cone up as a notification when the device finds a computer, bit there may be an override method in the dev settings

Comment: yeah that is why I am a bit confused, because there should be a notification that should tell me that i am connected and what options i want but no, it just charges. Also i have tried to find the "USB connection"   options in my setting but its not where people tell me it is... :(

Answer (score 1):

- First of all, please make sure that you have latest Samsung USB driver installed on your computer, if not please update it or download latest version from [this](http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000117) page.
- Second, make sure that USB cable is working properly.
- Third, if USB cable is ok, driver is up-to-date and you still won't able to connect, then type in your Phone app this string `*#7284#`and check the option `MTP + ADB`, press `save and reset`. This should solve connection issue.

P.S. If appeared `*#7284#`  "service screen" is different which means you can't see the `MTP + ADB` option please post the screenshot here.

Comment: Still nothing m8... idk I am probably missing something very obvious.